# populate a complex type in entity framework

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, .net-4.0, ado.net-entity-data-model

I have a complex type SalesOrderHeader with following properties:
OrderNumber
CustomerName
CustomerNumber
PODate
Comments
Invoice Number

I have created a stored procedure(function import) to populate these properties. In my procedure say uspGetDetails I use:

First select statement to fetch first 4 properties OrderNumber, CustomerName, CustomerNumber, PODate.

Second select Proprty to fetch Comments

3rd Select Property to fetch InvoiceNumber as below

```
CREATE PROCEDURE uspGetHeaderDetails
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@OrderNumber CHAR(21)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @Counter INT;
DECLARE @OrignalNumber INT;

SELECT @Counter = count(*) FROM sop10100 WHERE sopnumbe = @OrderNumber

IF @Counter > 0 
BEGIN
    SELECT TOP 1 sopnumbe [OrderNumber]
        , custname  [CustomerName]
        , custnmbr  [CustomerNumber]
        , cstponbr  [CustomerPhoneNumber]
        , docdate   [PODate]
        , orignumb  [OriginalNumber]
    FROM sop10100
    WHERE sopnumbe = @OrderNumber
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT TOP 1 sopnumbe [OrderNumber]
        , custname  [CustomerName]
        , custnmbr  [CustomerNumber]
        , cstponbr  [CustomerPhoneNumber]
        , docdate   [PODate]
        , orignumb  [OriginalNumber]
    FROM SOP30200
    WHERE sopnumbe = @OrderNumber
END

     SELECT cmmttext [Comments]

     FROM sop10106 WHERE sopnumbe = @OrderNumber

SELECT sopnumbe [InvoiceNumber]

     FROM sop30200 WHERE orignumb = @OrderNumber
END
```

And below is my method to execute this procedure to populate SalesOrderHeader

```
[AcceptVerbs("POST")]
public ActionResult SearchResult(FormCollection collection )
{
    string orderNumber = collection["searchItem"].ToString();
    Models.SalesEntities db = new Models.SalesEntities();
    ObjectParameter[] parameters = new ObjectParameter[1];
    parameters[0] = new ObjectParameter("OrderNumber", orderNumber);
    var headerResult = db.ExecuteFunction<Models.SalesOrderHeader>("uspGetHeaderDetails", parameters);

    Models.SalesOrderHeader salesOrderHeader = new Models.SalesOrderHeader();
    salesOrderHeader = headerResult.SingleOrDefault();

    return View(salesOrderHeader);
}
```

**PROBLEM:** When I Execute this, i get an error saying incompatible data, as the function import is fetching results of only foirst query. the results of 2nd and 3rd query ie comments and InvoiceNumber are not being picked.

Is it possible to populate one complex type by multiple queryies i a stored procedure?
If not then what is the other way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not possible with current version (4.0) of EF. Current version doesn't support stored procedures with multiple result sets (more than one select inside the procedure). This feature was previewed in June 2011 CTP and should be part of EFv4.5 (part of .NET 4.5).

At the moment the only way to use stored procedures returning multiple result sets is to use  [EFExtensions](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/EFExtensions) but the code is much [more complicated](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/meek/archive/2008/03/26/ado-entity-framework-stored-procedure-customization.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that your invoice number will actually start out in SOP10100 before it gets posted.  You will need to check SOP10100 first for the invoice number in SOPNUMBE then check SOP30200.  Remember, SOP10100 is the active SOP header table and SOP30200 is the historical SOP header table.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM SOP10100 WHERE ORIGNUMB = @OrderNumber)
    BEGIN
        SELECT SOPNUMBE [InvoiceNumber]
        FROM SOP10100 WHERE ORIGNUMB = @OrderNumber
    END
 ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT SOPNUMBE [InvoiceNumber]
        FROM SOP30200 WHERE ORIGNUMB = @OrderNumber
    END
```

Note the `IF` statement I used above.  Using the `count(*)` function to determine if the record you are looking for is in the active table or history table is more performance heavy than necessary.  The same idea can be used in your initial query:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM SOP10100 WHERE SOPNUMBE = @OrderNumber)
    BEGIN
        SELECT TOP 1 SOPNUMBE [OrderNumber]
            , CUSTNAME [CustomerName]
            , CUSTNMBR [CustomerNumber]
            , CSTPONBR [CustomerPhoneNumber]
            , DOCDATE [PODate]
            , ORIGNUMB [OriginalNumber]
        FROM SOP10100
        WHERE SOPNUMBE = @OrderNumber
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT TOP 1 SOPNUMBE [OrderNumber]
            , CUSTNAME [CustomerName]
            , CUSTNMBR [CustomerNumber]
            , CSTPONBR [CustomerPhoneNumber]
            , DOCDATE [PODate]
            , ORIGNUMB [OriginalNumber]
        FROM SOP30200
        WHERE SOPNUMBE = @OrderNumber
    END
```

As mentioned in the answer by Ladislav, you will likely need to break this stored procedure up into 3 different stored procedures until EF is updated to meet the demands of your project.